# Image in pygame gets distorted when replacing number with index

Tags: python, image, resize, pygame, transform

I'm not sure if there is a bug, something wrong with my images, or my code. When `greenScoreList[gfindex]` is a fixed number for example, it produces a good image (ignore the lack of transparency):

[image]

When `greenScoreList[gfindex]` depends on a score in each column of `greenScoreList`, the size of each `GreenFish` increases depending on how much the score increases. This produces a distorted image:

[image: i.imgur.com/c0bgVju.png]

```
def load_image(file, name, transparent, alpha):
    new_image = pygame.image.load(file)
    if alpha == True:
        new_image = new_image.convert_alpha()
    else:
        new_image = new_image.convert()
    if transparent:
        colorkey = new_image.get_at((0,0))
        new_image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
    images[name] = new_image

class GreenFish(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = images["spr_greenfish"]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        allsprites.add(self)
        self.random_direction()
        global greenWidth, greenHeight, greenScoreList
        greenWidth, greenHeight = (24, 8) #orig image size
        greenScoreList = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    def update(self):
        newpos = (self.rect.topleft[0]+self.direction[0],self.rect.topleft[1]+self.direction[1])
        self.rect.topleft = newpos
        for greenFish in greenfishes:
            gfindex = greenfishes.index(greenFish)
            #the image looks distorted when removing the line below
            greenScoreList[gfindex] = 50 #50 is as fixed number for example
            greenfishes[gfindex].image = pygame.transform.scale(greenfishes[gfindex].image, ((greenWidth+greenScoreList[gfindex]), greenHeight+greenScoreList[gfindex]))
    def collision_with_redFish(self, greenFishIndex):
        for i in range(5):
            if i == greenFishIndex:
                greenScoreList[i] += 10
                break
spr_greenfish = load_image("sprites/greenfish3.png", "spr_greenfish", True, True)
```

Comment: Does the fish get distorted if you change the constant to something really large like 1000 or something?

Comment: It does not get distorted when I change the constant to something really large. When I do 1000 it's too big, 500 is really big but it does not get distorted then.

Comment: Ok, I suspected the constant may not have been large enough to produce any noticeable change, and actually it is a flaw with how you are scaling the fish. Your experiments, however, disprove that conjecture.

Comment: I think it is zooming in the top left corner of the image. When I did 
            greenfishes[gfindex].image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(greenfishes[gfindex].image, ((greenWidth+3*greenScoreList[gfindex]), greenHeight+greenScoreList[gfindex]))

that is the ratio of the original image (24:8). When I ran it and the score increased, the top left part of the fish would be bigger and the bottom part would keep being smaller.

Comment: This is unsolved and I gave up on this.

Comment: @gamelanguage Don't give up yet! The long version is in my answer, but your problem is that you're stretching the image against its aspect ratio, and irregular distortion looks crazy strange, especially if you start compounding them over and over again. You need to multiply dimensions by a common factor instead of adding a fixed value to non-square images, and you should probably redraw an original of the copy instead of compounding your changes.

Comment: At least, if I've read your question correctly. I didn't have enough code to rebuild it entirely, but I think I get what you're angling at... :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it acted this way is because the update() function of the green fish depended on size. This would have been fixed if I reset the size back to images["spr_greenfish"] instead of doing pygame transform on it every single frame. Pygame does not like that.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that, since your value for `greenScoreList[gfindex]` is going to be an integer, the size ratio of `greenfishes[gfindex].image` will distort if the original image (as you've noted) is not a square.

Your original size is 24 x 8 px, which produces an undistorted image with an aspect ratio of exactly 3:1. In your first image, the dimensions are 74 x 58px (or 24+50 by 8+50; `50` from `greenScoreList[gfindex]`), which has a ratio of about 14:11 (1.276:1), and is already considerably distorted. In the next image you post, it's grown to 84 x 68px, or ten more over the last one, distorting its ratio further to about (21:17, or 1.235:1).

In short, adding a single value to the size of each axis will distort the original image more and more severely as it becomes more square-like. What you probably want to do instead is *multiply* the size of each dimension by a single *factor*, *based* on score, rather than the fixed value the score represents. Consider:

```
for greenFish in greenfishes:
    gfindex = greenfishes.index(greenFish)
    greenScoreList[gfindex] = 50 # The score for this greenFish can stay as fifty...
    imagescale = 1 + (greenScoreList[gfindex] / 25.0) 
      # ...but the score needs to be converted to a factor instead of a hard value...

    greenfishes[gfindex].image = pygame.transform.scale(greenfishes[gfindex].image, (int(greenWidth * imagescale), int(greenHeight * imagescale)))
      # The fish's incoming dimensions are rescaled according to a resizing factor, based on its score! The result still has to be an integer.
```

In this case, I've chosen to divide the score by 25.0 in order to keep the enlargement of the fish somewhat like the size increase you've shown (a score of 50 produces a fish about three times wider than zero), but the factor is up to you. Multiplying the dimensions instead of adding to them will preserve the aspect ratio of your original image (plus or minus a pixel or two), and keep your images looking clean!

I should also point out that serial transformation will almost certainly cause [generation loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) after even a few enlargements. You may wish to replace the transformation line with something like this to prevent that kind of distortion:

```
greenfishes[gfindex].image = pygame.transform.scale(images["spr_greenfish"], (int(greenWidth * imagescale), int(greenHeight * imagescale)))
```

...which uses a copy of the original greenfish image in the global library, instead of rescaling a 'stale' one.

As much as you can, you'll want to transform copies of *original images* instead of making *compound transformations*, in order to minimize the number of transformation artifacts each revision creates. Just make sure you don't alter the original (unintentionally)!

Comment: Incidentally, you may wish to simply assign a `score` attribute to each `GreenFish` object instead of carrying them all in a global list. It's a bit tidier, and you won't need to call global variables as soften (which, as I understand it, is more Pythonic, if you're into that stuff), and it's easier to handle on a fish-by-fish basis. You can recreate the list as you need it with something like `gfScoreList = [Fish.score for Fish in greenfishes]` if you ever need all of the scores at once for something!